# Ubuntu installer fails in various ways

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install from a ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso live USB drive. It fails in different ways depending on my choices to the installer.

**Way 1:** I boot the installer, connect to my wi-fi network, and check "Download updates while installing". I can get to the "Install Now" step, after "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" (with "Use LVM" checked, though that may not be important, since I tried other things below). I click "Install Now", a window pops up with the partition info, and I click permission to go ahead -- and then it seems to get stuck with a spinning cursor. (I waited at least 30 minutes, probably over an hour.) What might be wrong? What can I do to find out? Was it just downloading updates all that time without saying what it's doing?

The sha256sum of the ISO checks out. When I wrote it to the USB drive (using Rufus USB installer, following [the directions](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)), I set the "Check device for bad blocks" option, and it passed.

The first time I tried to install, I picked "Install alongside Windows" instead of "Erase disk", and it seemed to hang up the same way. Maybe it was repartitioning for hours while displaying the spinning white cursor and not letting me do anything -- that's plausible -- but the behavior I could see was the same. (I decided I didn't want the Windows install enough to wait more hours on repartitioning, and powered it off.)

**Way 2:** If instead I click the "Try Ubuntu" button at the start, the screen goes to text mode and an infinite list of printk messages scroll by too quickly to read. Bits I can make out sometimes: "*n* printk messages dropped"; "pcieport"; "PCIe bus error" (I think); "receiver layer error status" (I think?); "mask=00..."; "Physical Layer"; "id=00e0 (Receiver ID)".

**Way 3:** Like way 1, but without connecting to wifi, or checking "Download updates". Now it gets further, to setting up keyboard layout, my name and password, and time zone. It starts apparently installing the OS to disk. After a short wait, it reports "We're sorry, the installer crashed." saying it's out of disk space. If I had to guess, it might not have properly recovered from the interruption of the repartitioning from back when I tried Way 1, although AFAIK it should not matter because this fresh install is supposed to erase whatever was on the disk before.

This is a new Dell XPS 8900 which ran Windows 7 Professional with no problem.

**Update:** I did not figure this out but did manage to install Debian instead. It'd be good to have a better idea what went wrong, but I'm not going to mess with the Debian install.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Did you format the disks?

Comment: Thanks, @Fabby. I didn't do anything extra to format the hard drive, if that's what you mean -- I thought the  "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option did that. If you mean the USB drive, I used the default option from Ubuntu's instructions that I linked to above (ISOHybrid image, step 4 of https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows )

Comment: You've erased your disk anyway, so use [DBAN](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/) to fully nuke your disk and try again.  If that doesn't work, hit [ctrl][s] to stop the scrolling and leave another comment with the exact error message.

Comment: I did try ctrl-s originally and it did not pause it. There was a brief *change* in the messages scrolling by, too fast for me to see the new ones. I'll check out DBAN, thanks.

Comment: Did [pause] work?

Comment: Huh, I forgot about the Pause button. But alas, it doesn't pause it either. DBAN time!

Comment: So, the flash drive loaded with DBAN also hung. Not getting into details, but I just tried writing the flash drive from a MacBook instead of from Windows, and this time I got further: Ubuntu still complains that it's out of disk space almost right away, with the hard drive nowhere in the partition table. I was able to open a terminal and run fdisk, which reports "Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary." It looks reasonable AFAICT otherwise. I guess I could try also writing DBAN from Mac instead of Windows, and try running it again. Might that help on the reported sector issue?

Comment: Continued: still in the terminal, I repartitioned the hard drive with gparted. Then tried to shut down, and got the scrolling printk's again. Power cycled, booted to the installer, followed Way 3. It did not get quite as far this time: I picked the time zone, and "ubi-timezone failed with exit code 1" popped up. I chose "Quit"; soon after, a popup about low space or memory (I forget the exact word used, oops), and printk's. In summary, there seems to be a consistent problem about space/memory from the installer even though the hardware is ample.

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading/re-verifying the installer ISO file? Or have you tried a different usb disc? Something is clearly not right, ubuntu installs are typically painless. Also, are you using the correct UEFI or bios mode? If Debian installed okay, than I would think it's not a hardware problem with your disc, but possibly a problem with ubuntu not agreeing with some of your computers firmware. Perhaps secure boot is preventing a device driver from functioning correctly as well. You could always resort to removing your hd and installing ubuntu from another machine, if all else fails.

Comment: @Chev_603 I did re-download/re-verify when writing it from the MacBook. I didn't have another usb drive handy, unfortunately. The BIOS is in legacy mode instead of UEFI secure boot. (It's very plausible there's something important I don't understand about disabling secure boot, since it's been many years since last I installed Linux. But it seems I didn't have to change this setting from the factory default.) Thank you for the suggestions -- by now I don't want to mess with a working system anymore.

Comment: @DariusBacon The disk is fried anyway, might still be a problem in the partition table.  Go to gparted again, device - create new partition - msdos and try again.  Then leave another comment.

Comment: @DariousBacon - I understand that. Best of luck with Debian, it's also good distro. However, should you decide you need Ubuntu for whatever reason, I have had issues like this and ended up physically removing the drive and doing the install in another machine and than putting the drive back in. Tis very hacky, but worked and was easier than going through all the steps.

Comment: Nice idea! I'll keep it in mind for another time.